# Multiple boxplots of all categorical variables in one plotting window using seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

In the code below I'd like to loop through all categorical variables in "variables", and show separate boxplots of "fare" for all of them in a single plotting window. How do I do that? Thanks.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
variables = list(titanic.select_dtypes(include="object").columns)  # list of categorical variables
# single boxplot of fare vs passenger sex
g = sns.catplot(x="sex", y="fare", kind="box", data=titanic.query("fare>0"))
g.set(yscale="log")
```

Update: The following looping code seems to work, but I'd like some help with cleaning up the plot (attached below) if possible, namely removing the empty subplot window and interior axes ticks/labels. Thanks again.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)
i = j = 0
for variable in variables:
    g = sns.boxplot(x=variable, y="fare", data=titanic.query("fare>0"), ax=axs[i][j])
    g.set(yscale="log")
    j += 1
    if j>2:
        i += 1; j = 0
```

[image]

Update #2: YOLO's code below does the job. Thanks!

Comment: The accepted solution is elegant. I was trying to find a way to stick to `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3)` syntax. Turns out we can remove a subplot as well. Use `fig.delaxes(axs[1][2])` in your case to remove the empty plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

for i, c in enumerate(variables, 1):
    plt.subplot(2,3,i) 
    g = sns.boxplot(x=c, y="fare",data=titanic.query("fare>0"))
    g.set(yscale="log")
```

Comment: Thanks. But this code creates inlined boxplot windows one after another. I wanted to see if I could do subplotting inside one window, with something like ```fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)``` outside the loop, and calling each sub-window within the loop by passing ```ax=axs[]``` to ```sns.catplot().``` But this does not work.

Comment: Yes it does, thanks! I added an update before seeing your edit, so added another update pointing to your answer.